# XSLT 2.0 Group by for multiple elements

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm trying to group below XML on CC_code and Customer_Id but with current logic I'm grouping only on CC_code and not unique Customer_Id.

Sample XML is below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <env:Body>
        <wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="fin_file">
            <wd:Report_Entry>
                <wd:Customers>
                    <wd:Customer_ID>144122</wd:Customer_ID>
                </wd:Customers>
                <wd:Invoice_Lines>
                    <wd:Cost_Center wd:Descriptor="Appraisal Mgmt">
                    </wd:Cost_Center>
                    <wd:CC_code>22110</wd:CC_code>
                    <wd:Company_code>AT-12</wd:Company_code>
                     <wd:Currency>GBP</wd:Currency>
                </wd:Invoice_Lines>
                <wd:Invoice_Lines>
                    <wd:Cost_Center wd:Descriptor="Tax Other Cost Ctr">
                    </wd:Cost_Center>
                    <wd:CC_code>52600</wd:CC_code>
                     <wd:Company_code>AT-12</wd:Company_code>
                       <wd:Currency>GBP</wd:Currency>
                </wd:Invoice_Lines>
                <wd:Invoice_Lines>
                    <wd:Cost_Center wd:Descriptor="Appraisal">
                    </wd:Cost_Center>
                    <wd:CC_code>22110</wd:CC_code>
                    <wd:Company_code>AT-12</wd:Company_code>
                       <wd:Currency>GBP</wd:Currency>
                </wd:Invoice_Lines>
            </wd:Report_Entry>
            <wd:Report_Entry>
                <wd:Customers>
                    <wd:Customer_ID>144133</wd:Customer_ID>
                </wd:Customers>
                <wd:Invoice_Lines>
                    <wd:Cost_Center wd:Descriptor="Appraisal Mgmt">
                    </wd:Cost_Center>
                    <wd:CC_code>22110</wd:CC_code>
                <wd:Company_code>AT-12</wd:Company_code>
                       <wd:Currency>GBP</wd:Currency>
                </wd:Invoice_Lines>
                <wd:Invoice_Lines>
                    <wd:Cost_Center wd:Descriptor="Appraisal Mgmt">
                    </wd:Cost_Center>
                    <wd:CC_code>22110</wd:CC_code>
                     <wd:Company_code>AT-12</wd:Company_code>
                       <wd:Currency>GBP</wd:Currency>
                </wd:Invoice_Lines>
            </wd:Report_Entry>
        </wd:Report_Data>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

**Expected Result in text format:**

144122/22110|Appraisal Mgmt|AT-12|GBP

144122/52600|Tax Other Cost Ctr|AT-12|GBP

144133/22110|Appraisal Mgmt|AT-12|GBP

Comment: I've removed the `group-by` tag, as it refers only to the SQL GROUP BY statement. Please read the description of tags before using them. Tags have relevance and meaning here, and using them properly is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 3 you can use a composite grouping key e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    xpath-default-namespace="fin_file"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group 
       select="//Report_Entry/Invoice_Lines"
       composite="yes"
       group-by="../Customers/Customer_ID, CC_code">
       <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key(), Cost_Center/@*:Descriptor" separator=" | "/>
       <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XSLT 2.0 you can form a single key by concatenating the two values e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    xpath-default-namespace="fin_file"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each-group 
       select="//Report_Entry/Invoice_Lines"
       composite="yes"
       group-by="concat(../Customers/Customer_ID, '/', CC_code)">
       <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key(), Cost_Center/@*:Descriptor" separator=" | "/>
       <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Just one follow up question, if more elements like company code and currency are needed in output how could we modify this XSLT 2.0 ?
I have added the elements in XML. Thanks again

Comment: @HarshitSingh, as those example elements are children of the `Invoice_Lines` element it should be quite obvious that you just need to select them in the `value-of` e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key(), Cost_Center/@*:Descriptor, Company_code, Currency" separator=" | "/>`